# How do I include a dynamic filename?

Tags: shell, loops, filenames, wget

I would like to fetch a file that has a dynamic file name.

http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/hur/prod/hur.2014111900/invest97e.2014111900.grib.f00.grib2

The dynamic part I am not sure how to change is "invest97e." Is there wildcard I could use or do I need to read the index file?

Here is my current script

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# variables
#

basedir="http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/hur/prod/hur."
date=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
datetime="${date}00"
basename="{*}.${datetime}.grib.f"

i=0
hh="00"

#
# main
#

while [ $hh != "126" ]
do
    hh=`printf "%0.2d" $i`
    echo $hh
    i=`expr $i + 6`
    url="${basedir}${basename}${hh}.grib2"
    wget -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url
done;
```

Comment: Does that bit of the name mean something? Also does that name actually change much? There appear to only be two `hur` folders under `prod` the older one is `96e` and the newer one is `97e` but even the new one is six months old.

Comment: the name will change regularly. It will not necessarily be the same with a different number.  The name could be "albert" or "krista" as an example. The rest of the file name will be the same with the exception of the data and hour (identified as f00) in the link provided. The name corresponds to active tropical weather systems. If a system has not been named yet, it is called, "invest." The files are old right now, but this will change soon.

Comment: Ah. That explains the relative lack of data then. If there isn't a pattern to the names or a way to find the name via some other channel then yes, you need to use the index. That being said you could try to get `wget` to do the work for you by using the spidering mode with appropriate patterns and limits.